# Prevent users from logging in with local admin

Tags: windows, security, administrator, uac

We are looking to implement the principal of least privilege accounts in our company.  Our software development team requires administrator rights to perform their work so we're considering creating a separated local admin account for elevated tasks.  However, we do not want our developers to use this account to login as we want them to use their domain (least privilege) accounts.

How can we prevent our developers from logging in with the local admin account and force the domain account usage?  Would deploying a GPO script to auto logout the account if detected that the local admin account has logged in be a feasible way to deter admin login?

Can anyone share their experience on how to manage the local admin account usage?

Thanks

Comment: A simple solution would be to disable the local admin account, to be enabled by booting into Safe mode. See also [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/software-restriction-policies/administer-software-restriction-policies).

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way.
As long as developers need to run things as admin, you will have to grant them the privilege to logon locally which implies the ability to logon as administrative user. What I use myself as a workaround is the following (and please don't think it's insecure even if it sounds that way) which I have published as article here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24599/Free-yourself-of-your-administrative-account.html
That way, you can workaround this problem of full logon as administrative user!